# Converting do-while to for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, do-while

At the moment, I have this:

```
 do{
           if (i < y){ //y is a constant

               ObsHandler.obsPartsHandler(); //increment i twice
               ObsHandler.search(); 

           }
           else { 
               break;
           }

       } while (!endline.equals(null)); // endline is changed during each loop cycle
```

With this loop, and the inputs I have, endline can not be null; this renders the while loop breaking condition redundant. When I try and convert this loop to a for loop, I get a misplaced construct error from Eclipse.

i.e:

```
for (i < y) {
       ObsHandler.obsPartsHandler(); //increment i twice
       ObsHandler.search(); }
```

Whilst, the while loop I have works, it seems like bad practice to me. 
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: 99% of for loops are used to go through an array/collection. For other stuff use a while loop. Your code is ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need to check `endLine`, you can still use a while loop:

```
while (i < y) {    
    ObsHandler.obsPartsHandler(); //increment i twice
    ObsHandler.search(); 
}
```

If you also need to check `endLine`:

```
while (i < y && !endline.equals(null)) {    
    ObsHandler.obsPartsHandler(); //increment i twice
    ObsHandler.search(); 
}
```

Note: the difference between do / while (your initial code) and while { } is that in the first case the loop is always run at least once. With a while { }, it is not run at all if the condition is not true at the beginning. That is the same behaviour as a for loop (won't run if the condition is false before the loop).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I just wasn't sure if a while loop was the correct form.

Comment: This loop is indeed the correct form. But I strongly advise changing `i` and `y` to something a little more meaningful.

Comment: Normally, I'd agree but in the context of the entire project they are meaningful.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use a `for` loop, you need to have all three parts of a standard `for`.  Since you have two conditions, they need to be both included in the condition part:

```
for ( ; i < y && !endline.equals(null); ) {
    ObsHandler.obsPartsHandler();
    ObsHandler.search();
}
```

You probably have some initialization code for `i`, like `i=0`, which could also go into the initialization section of the `for` loop.  Otherwise, if all you have is a set of conditions to check without some array or list you are iterating, `while` or `do` is really the better fit.

Comment: I like the whole statement except that `while or do is a better fit`. While loops were designed for waiting on a logical condition. For loops were specifically made for the specific logical condition of "I want to run x number of times". The convention can be broken and either used as either, but bottom line if you know exactly how many times to execute, a for loop is superior to a while loop specifically for the reason you outlined, which is that your index variable can be init'd with the for loop, thus limiting its scope.

Comment: @corsiKa: Good point, thanks for adding your input.  It does seem in this case `while` would be ok simply because the conditions are modified directly as a side-effect in `ObsHandler.obsPartsHandler()`, rather than some index or counter that is incremented throughout the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I was just seeking reassurance that this use of a while loop would not be frowned upon.

Comment: @SeanKenny: I would double-check for one-off error, because I'm not sure I've captured the meaning exactly how I've combined the conditions.

Comment: @SeanKenny What is frowned upon is using `i` as a variable that gets changed in multiple methods like that. Not only is it making debugging difficult for that because `i` is a HORRIBLE variable name for anything other than a simple for loop, but it also will confuse anyone else who tries to use for loop. If they accidentially make their for loop somewhere else in the code go `for(i = 0; i <...` and for get the `int` (which happens late in the day/night...) then it's a bug that might go undetected for quite a while.

Answer (score 2):

A `while` loop seems like the natural choice for your code. I would just simplify it to:

```
do {
  ObsHandler.obsPartsHandler(); //increment i twice
  ObsHandler.search(); 
} while (i < y && !endline.equals(null)); // endline is changed during each loop cycle
```

or, if you need to check the conditions before:

```
while (i < y && !endline.equals(null)) {
  ObsHandler.obsPartsHandler(); //increment i twice
  ObsHandler.search();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (boolean start=true;(start || endline != null) && i < y;){
    start=false;
    ObsHandler.obsPartsHandler(); //increment i twice
    ObsHandler.search();
}
```

`(startendline != null)` is only tested the second time.
`i < y` is only tested the first time.

Comment: What is the purpose of the boolean?

Comment: The question mentions that is not possible for endline to equal null and that the outer loop condition is not longer needed.

Comment: fair enough but I think the original poster was confused about what he was trying to achieve - what you show is equivalent to a do / while but that's not necessarily what he wanted. See the note at the bottom of my answer.